Invertir un array eficientemente
Estoy tratando de invertir el orden de los elementos en un array en JavaScript.
¿Cuál es la manera más eficiente de hacerlo?
// Actualmente tengo un array como este:
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

He intentado usar un bucle for para hacerlo manualmente, pero me pregunto si hay una forma más sencilla o más eficiente.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Hola Matias, bienvenido, para evitar que te cierren la pregunta o recibir votos negativos, te sugiero que la edites, y agregues en ella, el código que has intentado (como texto).

Esta pregunta en inglés es interesante https://stackoverflow.com/q/5276953

invertir un array ... motivo de cierre: debe estar mas enfocada ... WTH como se consigue que este más enfocada, no puede ser más literal y canonico (La palabra canónico hace referencia, en general, a todo aquello que se ajusta a los cánones o a las reglas)...

Al ser javascript lo que estas ejecutando, dependera mucho del volumen de datos en el array y el equipo cliente que se este usando o el equipo servidor (por que si javascript ahora tambien se puede ejecutar en el backend)
Una forma para mi eficiente (desde el punto de vista del codigo y su organizacion) seria:


let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]



Nota: aqui estamos implementando el metodo .reverse()
En tal caso que no queramos alterar el array original tambien podemos hacer algo asi:


let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let reversedArr = [...arr].reverse();
console.log(reversedArr); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (el array original no se modifica)




Para no alterar el array original también se podría usar map. arr.map((e, i, a)=> a[(a.length -1) -i]).

si .map seria el método genérico para recorrer el array y hacer cualquier cosa que lo requiera ... pero prefiero implementar un método que ya sé que está definido para cumplir con la responsabilidad ... el otro tema es que ver en el código el método map un novato no podría asociar que se está haciendo a menos que conozca el código y lo que se pretendía ... por otro lado si ves el método .reverse ... es mucho más intuitivo y literal.
